# Excel VBA UDF assign values to a Range according to certain criteria

Tags: vba, excel, range

first question on Stack Overflow here. I'm quite new to VBA so please bear with my question.

I'm trying to run regressions using User Defined Function, and I would like to generate two range variables that are filtered according to a criteria.

For example, in Sheet1 I have: 
[image: X variables in Column A, Y variables in Column B]

And I would like to run a regression with Xs and Ys when X is smaller than 0.3.

Previously I tried a code using For loop to assign values to the range:

```
Dim X As Range
Dim Y As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

j = 1

With ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To 100

    If Cells(i, 1).Value < 0.3 Then

    X(j) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Y(j) = Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If

j = j + 1

Next i

End With
```

And apparently it doesn't work so I didn't proceed to the regression part. Could anyone help me correct this?

Alternatively, I've been thinking about whether it's possible to get the whole range of values first and then delete some of them.

Now I have set X and Y ready:

```
Set X = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(7, 1))
Set Y = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(7, 2))
```

But I'm not sure what the possible ways are to delete (not setting them to 0 or empty) some units in these range variables. Could anyone help me with that as well?

Thanks everyone for helping me.

Comment: When you call the regression function, do you need to pass all the X's and Y's at once or only one pair?  If you only need to pass one pair, your first solution looks ok. Why did it not worked?

Comment: How are you intending to do the regression? If the input must be a range, you could transfer the appropriate values to an array and then write them to the sheet.

Comment: @SergioPrats Hi Sergio, I tried my first solution but then when I use the Application.Worksheetfunction.LINEST code and use these two ranges I just created, it returns error (#Value). And to be honest I'm not sure if range variables values can be assigned this way - is this syntax correct? I know that for a whole range I need to use "Set", but for individual variables I'm not sure.

Comment: @SJR Hi SJR, I was intended to run the regression inside the user defined function, because I need to apply a series of criteria and run several regressions accordingly. It would be too troublesome to write them to sheet every time.

Comment: Perhaps just use arrays then. Still not clear on your method of calculating.